# Generate vertical images for text

Tags: html, image, text, generator

I need vertical headers in html table.
Pure CSS solution is not enough for some reasons, so we decided to generate images with vertical text on them and put in appropriate th elements.

We have about 200 headers, so some automation is wanted.

Can you advice some tools which can help to do it with less efforts?

Answer (score 0):

Adobe Photoshop is scriptable; you can create text layers, set text, rotate them, trim the image, and save the file out all procedurally. Do you have a copy of Photoshop that you can use?

With less learning overhead (or $$$ spent), you could alternatively [create text on an HTML canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/drawing_text_using_a_canvas) and then [create a PNG data url](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#dom-canvas-todataurl). With this, you could include the content for your 200 headers directly in your CSS instead of making 200 HTTP requests to pull them all over.

Comment: Thanks, I already used ImageMagick tool suite. That was enough for me.